# Converting Binary File to Text File in C

Tags: c, text, binary

I'm having an issue trying to convert a Binary File into a text file. Right now, I'm getting an output of "hello 16". I should be getting 5 lines of output, in which the first line should be "hello 32". I'm unsure where I went wrong, but I've been trying to figure it out for a few hours now.
[Link to Binary File](https://gyazo.com/7252ca6fa6f36a1f430c93839cdd9110)

```
void BinaryToText(char *inputFile, char *outputFile) {
    unsigned char str[256];
    unsigned int num;
    int fileLen;

    FILE *finp;
    FILE *fout;

    finp = fopen(inputFile, "r");
    fout = fopen(outputFile, "w");

    fseek(finp, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileLen = ftell(finp);
    fseek(finp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    while (fread(&fileLen, sizeof(char), 1, finp) == 1) {
        fread(&str, sizeof(str), 1, finp);
        fread(&num, sizeof(int), 1, finp); 
        fprintf(fout, "%s %d\n", str, num);
    }
    fclose(finp);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: hard to answer without details of the format of binary file

Comment: Just updated the description with a link to the binary file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You binary file format seems awkward:

- you open the input file with `"r"`: it should be opened in binary mode with `"rb"`.
- you first attempt to determine the file size with `ftell()`. Be aware that this will not work for pipes and devices.  In you case it would not matter as you do not use `fileLen` anyway.
- in the loop:

  - you read a single byte that you store in a part of `fileLen`.
  - you then read a string of 256 bytes.
  - you read a number directly, assuming the byte order and size of `int` is what you expect.
  - you then print the string, assuming there was a `'\0'` in the file, otherwise you would invoke undefined behavior.

It is hard to tell what is wrong without seeing the writing code.

Note that the binary file should be open with `"rb"` to prevent spurious conversion of linefeed sequences on some platforms, notably Windows.

**EDIT:**

Form the extra information provided in the comments, here is a modified version that should parse you binary file more appropriately:

```
void BinaryToText(char *inputFile, char *outputFile) {
    unsigned char str[256];
    unsigned int num;  // assuming 32 bit ints
    int i, len;

    FILE *finp = fopen(inputFile, "rb");
    FILE *fout = fopen(outputFile, "w");

    while ((len = fgetc(finp)) != EOF) {
        fread(str, len, 1, finp);
        str[len] = '\0';
        num  = (unsigned int)fgetc(finp) << 24;
        num |= fgetc(finp) << 16;
        num |= fgetc(finp) << 8;
        num |= fgetc(finp);
        fprintf(fout, "%s %d\n", (char*)str, num);
    }
    fclose(finp);
    fclose(fout);
}
```

Comment: [link]https://gyazo.com/7252ca6fa6f36a1f430c93839cdd9110

Edit: Here is a picture of the binary file I was unable to paste it into a codeblock

Comment: @AlexPurpleHosein: it would be more useful to post the code that produces the binary file.  The specification seems incorrect.

Comment: This is the given input and output files in which i need to match there is no current code which produces it [link]https://gyazo.com/6837218c5e35909b9ce69f0f25cbbc2b

Comment: @AlexPurpleHosein: can you produce a hex dump of the binary file?  You method for reading it is definitely incorrect.  The first byte seems to be the number of bytes in the string, followed by a number stored in big endian format.  I shall update my answer with code that parses your file.